# How to put array values in a string or integer?

Tags: iphone

Can anybody please tell me how to put array values into a string  or integer.

Suppose an array a=[1,2,3].

After converting it should be like

1) string=123

and for integer it should be

number=123.

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YOu can join the array and then convert it to it

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

NSString *string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];
int integer = [string intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code.

```
NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (id  obj in yourArray)
{
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
    [result appendFormat:@"%@", obj];
    }
}

NSLog(@"result = %@",result);
```